# Passing Value From View To View Model

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a Xaml Page With A textbox And a button When the User Clicks the Button The text box value should be passed to its viewModel. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xaml:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding TextBoxAContent} />
<Button Command={Binding ButtonCommand} />
```

view model code should be something like this:

```
class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _textBoxAContent;
    public string TextBoxAContent
    {
       get {return _textBoxAContent;}
       set {
              _textBoxAContent = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("TextBoxAContent");
           } 
    }

    public ICommand ButtonCommand
    {
       get
       {
            return new RelayCommand(ProcessTextHandler);
       }
    }

    private void ProcessTextHandler()
    {
       //add your code here. You can process your textbox`s text using TextBoxAContent property.
    }
}
```

You should also assign your viewmodel to view via `DataContext` property of the view control. (simply in constructor)

```
public MainPage()
{
    DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
}
```

**UPD**

p.s. RelayCommand & ViewModelBase - classes from [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)